# How to change \headsepline color in KOMA-Scriptclasses

Tags: header-footer, color, koma-script

At the moment I am working on a rather big project in which I typeset a lecture note for a professor of mine. I want to use the `headsepline` the KOMA Script Class offers, but I want it to have the same color as the headlinecolor I defined by adding

```
\renewcommand{\headfont}{\color{schrift}\normalfont\slshape}
```

Is there a solution for this with KOMA Script means or do I have to define it myself (in a way I don't know as I don't really know how to do such things at all)?

Example:

```
\documentclass[oneside, twocolumn=false, 12pt, headsepline=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{delarray, graphicx, url, fancybox, calc, cancel, caption, mathtools, amsmath, amssymb, wrapfig, subcaption, floatrow, amsthm, lipsum}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[margin={0.08\paperwidth,0.10\paperheight}, heightrounded]{geometry}

\usepackage[onlytext]{MinionPro}

\parindent 0pt
\parskip 6pt

\usepackage[pdftex, colorlinks=true,pdfstartview=FitB,bookmarks=false, urlcolor=schrift, linkcolor=schrift]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor=schrift,
  linktoc=all
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\l@section}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.6em}}
\renewcommand{\l@subsection}{\@dottedtocline{2}{4.0em}{3.6em}}
\renewcommand{\l@subsubsection}{\@dottedtocline{3}{7.4em}{4.5em}}
\makeatother

\fboxrule0pt

\definecolor{rahmen}{RGB}{0,73,114}
\definecolor{grund}{RGB}{238,241,251}          
\definecolor{schrift}{RGB}{0,73,114}

\captionsetup{format=plain, labelfont={color=rahmen,bf}}

%\usepackage[nomath]{kpfonts}

\SetSymbolFont{letters}{normal}{OML}{cmbr}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{normal}{OT1}{cmbr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{normal}{OMS}{cmbr}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf} {OT1}{cmbr}{bx}{n}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\color{schrift}\bfseries}

\renewcommand{\headfont}{\color{schrift}\normalfont\slshape}

\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{-}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\cdot$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{$\circ$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{$\bullet$}

\captionsetup{format=plain, labelfont={color=schrift,bf}}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\newcommand{\defeq}{\vcentcolon=}
\newcommand{\eqdef}{=\vcentcolon}

\hfuzz 100pt
\hbadness 10000

\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace *{-\baselineskip }}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is just some test chapter}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[5]
\lipsum[6]

\lipsum[7]

\end{document}
```

My problem is this output which I want to be in matching color

[image: Headlinesep by KOMA]

The option `[headlinesep]` added to the KOMA Script class I am using adds a horizontal bar between header and the body of the page.

There has been help in the comments I should just use the `\scrlayer-scrpage` Style, as it offered all the functions I have been looking for. But it appeared, that there more errors to cope with - I'll post my test document code here. Everything that is important allready is in the code

```
\documentclass[twoside=false, twocolumn=false, 12pt, ngerman, headsepline=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{delarray, graphicx, url, fancybox, calc, cancel, caption, amssymb, amsmath, mathtools, wrapfig, floatrow, amsthm, scrlayer-scrpage, lipsum}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}

\usepackage[margin={0.08\paperwidth,0.10\paperheight}, heightrounded]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace *{-\baselineskip }}

\usepackage[frenchmath]{MinionPro}

\parindent 0pt
\parskip 6pt
%\baselinestretch

%\usepackage[nomath]{kpfonts}
%\SetSymbolFont{letters}{normal}{OML}{cmbr}{m}{it}
%\SetSymbolFont{operators}{normal}{OT1}{cmbr}{m}{n}
%\SetSymbolFont{symbols}{normal}{OMS}{cmbr}{m}{n}
%\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbf} {OT1}{cmbr}{bx}{n}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\color{schrift}\bfseries}
\setheadsepline{1pt}[\color{schrift}]
\renewcommand{\headfont}{\color{schrift}\normalfont\slshape}

\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{-}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\cdot$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{$\circ$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{$\bullet$}

\fboxrule0pt

\definecolor{rahmen}{RGB}{0,73,114}
\definecolor{grund}{RGB}{238,241,251}          
\definecolor{schrift}{RGB}{0,73,114}

\usepackage[pdftex, colorlinks=true,pdfstartview=FitB,bookmarks=false, urlcolor=schrift, linkcolor=schrift]{hyperref}

\captionsetup{format=plain, labelfont={color=rahmen,bf}}

\newcommand{\defeq}{\vcentcolon=}
\newcommand{\eqdef}{=\vcentcolon}

\hfuzz 40pt
\hbadness 10000

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}

\addto\captionsngerman{
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Aufgabe}}

\parskip 6pt
\parindent 0pt

\makeatletter
\let\stdl@section\l@section
\renewcommand*{\l@section}[2]{%
  \stdl@section{\textcolor{black}{#1}}{\textcolor{black}{#2}}}
\let\stdl@subsection\l@subsection
\renewcommand*{\l@subsection}[2]{%
  \stdl@subsection{\textcolor{schrift}{#1}}{\textcolor{black}{#2}}}
\makeatother

\deftripstyle{versionheading}[][1pt]%
{22.08.2014}{\headmark}{}%
{}{\pagemark}{}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is just some testing chapter}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[5]
\lipsum[6]
\lipsum[7]

\paragraph{Error Prompt 1}

\begin{verbatim}
    Package scrlayer-scrpage Warning: Command \deftripstyle is deprecate.
(scrlayer-scrpage) You should replace it by \deftriplepagestyle,
(scrlayer-scrpage) e.g., on input line 64.
\end{verbatim}

But when I do as the error prompt is telling me, it says the command was undefined.

\end{document}
```

It now prints the `headsepline` in the color I desired but the defined pagestyle doesn't work which is why I cant adjust the thickness of the `headsepline` even though it is shown exactly like this in the KOMA Manual.. Please help me, I have no clue whats going on there! I hope anyone here knows how to deal with the errors because I am completely lost.

The Code produces this:

[image: output of examplecode 2]

Comment: `\newcommand{\generalheadcolor}{schrift}` and use `\generalheadcolor` in both cases?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ Christian Hupfer I am sorry for having not added an example, I thought there might have been somebody out there who knew the problem - but after thinking about it its of course the better solution because everyone can have a look at the problem now without having to read manuals to see what I mean.

Comment: Well, thanks for MWE. As far as I know, the KOMA classes do not store the colours for particular elements of the layout commands.

Comment: Unrelated to the question – there are a number of possible improvements: `\renewcommand{\l@section}` doesn't look very KOMA-like... IIRC for toc layout there is the KOMA-Script package `tocbasic`. The assignments `\parindent 0pt` and `\parskip 6pt` most definitely are wrong. Better use KOMA-Scripts `parskip` option. `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` most certainly isn't needed, `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` should suffice. I'm also not sure you need the `caption` package: the setup you're doing seems to be doable using KOMA-Script's own caption formatting...

Comment: btw: you should use `setkomafont` and `addkomafont` for changes. I also think there is an example of changing the color in the manual.

Comment: If you design your headers and footers using KOMA-Script's `scrlayer-scrpage` then you could use `\setkomafont{headsepline}{\color{whatever}}`

Comment: @cgnieder The command to change the headsepline color produced an error, namely "! Package scrkbase Error: font of element `headsepline' can't be set."

Well you are most probably right with what you're saying about my code, but I dont know how to set up the captions the way I do with KOMA nor do I see how to set the parskip option in KOMA. Additionaly: The commands given in "scrguien.pdf" are - as TeXMaker says - not defined, what is going wrong there?

Comment: @Friedrich As I said (or at least tried to say in my previous comment): the KOMA font `headsepline` only exists if you use the `scrlayer-scrpage` package. Details on the package and those options are explained in chapter 5 of the KOMA-Script manual.

Comment: @cgnieder Okay, I see. Some scr features were already available without loading any package so I thought they were preloaded automatically - thanks anyway, it now works. Could you pm me about the other changes you suggestet? I'm not good at programming my own stuff in TeX as I never read into it at all so there is a good chance the commands I use that are a little advanced are copied from solved problems around the internet.

Comment: @Friedrich *all* `scr...` packages and features are part of the KOMA-Script bundle but not all are loaded by default. Some of them have to be loaded explicitly. TeX.sx has no PMs. Me or someone else could put together the things in an answer. I'll do it if I have a bit more time.

Comment: With package scrlayer-scrpage loaded I still recieve a compiling error - I wanted to use it to define an own pagestyle and additionaly change the colors in the way I wanted to in the first place. I'll add the problem to the question I posted.

Answer (score 4):

I took the liberty to write up an answer, making your very large
example into a minimal one. As @cgnieder stated in the comments,
package `scrlayer-scrpage` defines an interface for defining page
headers and footer; mostly compatible with `scrpage2`. Mostly,
what does that mean? You received a warning, telling you that the
command `deftripstyle` is deprecated. True, it is. But it gives
you an alternative, and looking into the KOMA-documentation reveals:
You can just change the command name. *But* using this is not
recommended any more and is just there for compatibility reasons.

Is there any reason for making the document look like the
standard W0rd stuff? You should also consider using the class
*scrreprt*. @cgnieder made you aware of some other oddities in
the comments.

Be careful, you are loading packages twice.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\addtokomafont{headsepline}{\color{blue}}
\KOMAoptions{headsepline=10pt:\textwidth}
\renewcommand{\headfont}{\color{blue}\normalfont\slshape}
\newcommand{\versiondate}{\today}
\deftriplepagestyle{draftpages}[5pt]
{\versiondate}{\headmark}{}
{Draft}{\pagemark}{}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\clearpage
\pagestyle{draftpages}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I hope to tidy up my preamble soon, any suggestion is appreciated - eMail would be "friedrich-(at)hotmail.de"

Comment: What suggestions do you mean exactely?

Comment: Concerning the "oddities", I'm very aware of having some in my code but the KOMA Documentation alone is one big piece of text to go through which I am planning to do for sure, but that is going to take some time...